# Add user in ubuntu

Tags: permissions, users, system, accounts

I know there is many threads with this question, but they're asking for how to clone root and etc. I want to create a user that hans't got root privileges but it can install packages and etc... I want to download package and compile a file, but I don't want to risk with root account(it may damage my system) so want to create account that cannot delete/edit system files.

Comment: @MarkKirby Not literally _any user_, the user must be included in `/etc/sudoers`, of course with a relevant record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can can create an account but don't include this account as with sudo access.  The user can download and compile.  He can also test the compiled packages from his space.  Without the `sudo` access, he won't be able to install the package systemwide.

After compiling the package he can submit the compiled directory to you, or to someone who has `sudo` access so that you or another user with `sudo` access could install the it.

Downloading and compiling don't requite elevated access.  Only the installing part.

By default when you create a user, from the users configuration via `gear`, the user won't have `sudo` access unless specifically applied.

If you give a trusted user `sudo` access, he virtually has the same access as you.

Answer (score 0):

The root account in Ubuntu is disabled by default. You always login with regular users accounts. Regular users can obtain [elevated privileges in order to install packages with `sudo`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo).

The ability to *install packages* or *compile* implies changes in the system files/folder. You cannot have one without the other: If a given user can install software, the user must be able to change system files as well.

Comment: So there is no other option without adding a new user and then add it to 'visudo' ?